# Image orientation maps

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, computer-vision

What is the most common way to get 4 Orientaton maps at  0, 45, 90 and 135 angles from Image.
I want to apply orientation kernels. Is that good solution ?

for 0 orientation
-1 -1 -1
  2  2  2
-1 -1 -1

for 45 orientation
-1 -1 2
-1 2 -1
2 -1 -1

for 90 orientation
-1 2 -1
-1 2 -1
-1 2 -1

for 135 orientation
2 -1 -1
-1 2 -1
-1 -1 2

Cheers,
roboto

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You didn't format your matrices/maps. I think you mean [[-1,-1,-1],[2,2,2],[-1,-1,-1] for the 0 orientation and so forth. What do you mean by orientation maps? The first one is basically just the sum of the negative of the second order finite differences taken in the vertical direction for a pixel and its two horizontal neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that these are indeed 3x3 kernels, and that by "orientation maps" you mean crude indication of orientation on the smallest scale - yes, this'll do.

If you are not sure what exactly you want, your best shot is to implement these kernels, take a look a the results on a couple of examples, and decide whether you like what you see, and if not, why - and then come back here if you want to.